# Create an array and add 1 to each object in a loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a program who will create an array and add 1 to each object in a loop and as you can see when you run the code more than 1 is added to each object please help me

```js
var n1 = [];
var y = 0;
var z = 0
ola();

function ola() {
  var bola = setInterval(soma, 500);
  ola2();
}

function soma() {
  n1.push(y);
  console.log("ny: " + n1[y]);
  console.log("y: " + y);
  console.log("length: " + n1["length"]);
  console.log(n1);
  y++;
  ola2();
}

function ola2() {
  var p = y - 1;
  for (var x = p; x < y; x++) {
    n1[x] = z;
    z++;
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the current result always has 2 of the largest number, `1, 2, 3, 3`,
and you want only 1 number, `1, 2, 3`?
If so remove the `n1.push(y)`.

```js
var n1 = [];
var y = 0;
var z = 0
ola();

function ola() {
  var bola = setInterval(soma, 500);
  ola2();
}

function soma() {
  // n1.push(y);
  console.log("ny: " + n1[y]);
  console.log("y: " + y);
  console.log("length: " + n1["length"]);
  console.log(n1);
  y++;
  ola2();
}

function ola2() {
  var p = y - 1;
  for (var x = p; x < y; x++) {
    n1[x] = z;
    z++;
  }
}
```